# What are some good books for Computational Bayesian Statistics?

Tags: bayesian, references, computational-statistics

There is already a community wiki on introductory textbooks for Bayesian statistics.

However, I am looking for a book(s) on Computational Bayesian Statistics for intermediate learner who already has a good knowledge of Monte Carlo method and its applications (e.g. sampling method, MCMC, etc.). It should be up-to-date as the field is changing quickly.

Comment: [Stan resource](https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/external) could be quite helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty out there but here are some of my preferred ones:

- Robert C.P. (@Xi'an) and Casella G. *Monte Carlo Statistical Methods*, 2nd edition, Springer, 2010.
- Liu J.S. *Monte Carlo Strategies in Scientific Computing*, Springer, 2004.

Another one that fills the bill, which stands up in my to-be-read book pile, is:

- Chopin N. and Papaspiliopoulos O. *An Introduction to Sequential Monte Carlo*, Springer, 2020.

Comment: There is a [Bayesian Methods for Hackers](https://amzn.to/3Mgw4MJ) from 2015. And the 2011 [Hanbook of MCMC](https://amzn.to/3rDwjbp) stands its ground, ten years later. The 2018 [Handbook of Approximate Bayesian Computation](https://amzn.to/3Towa7F) is solely about ABC, but quite commendable and up to date.